# Seeking a cross reference between the Jerusalem and Babylonian Talmuds

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

The Bavli and Yerushalmi overlap in content (to a large extent), but the pagination of the overlapping content differs.

I am seeking a reference work that shows on what page(s) given topics in one version of the Talmud are to be found in the other version.

Comment: Are you familiar with the יפה עינים in the back of standard gemaras?

Comment: @אילפא I am not familiar with  יפה עינים .  Please tell me what it contains.

Answer (score 6):

**In time order we have:**

**1)** **ספר ללאת** published in 5626 by [Rabbi Meir Mairim Shafit](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%98) is available [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/32981) and [here](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/seforim/sefer_lulaos.pdf).

**2)** The **יפה עינים** by [Rabbi Aryeh Leib Yellin](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F) that appears after masechtos in the Vilna Shas (*as mentioned in a comment above*).

**3)** Some years ago, Professor Michael Sokoloff of Bar Ilan made his extensive listing [**מקבילות לירושלמי**](https://web.archive.org/web/20230323105712/https://www2.biu.ac.il/js/tl/yerushalmi/records.html) available in downloadable PDFs (*the original URL is now a dead link and only available via the Internet Archive and is a bit slow in loading*).

**4)** The [**Yerushalmi Meshulav**](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/calendars/yeru-meshulav.htm) program has links to nice PDF charts for relevant masechtos

**5)** As an aside, the recent [**ספר דרכי התלמודים**](https://files.daf-yomi.com/files/bookfiles/darkey-hatalmudim/darkey-hatalmudim.pdf) is not a listing of cross references but takes a deeper dive into analyzing differences between Yerushalmi and Bavli.